# How to protect passwords on a AppHarbor-app, with service-hook to GitHub

Tags: security, github, password-protection, credentials, appharbor

What are possible patterns around solving this problem on a **AppHarbor**-app that gets pushed to every time a push is done on it's opensource **GitHub**-project?

Say I have sensitive passwords stored in my `AppSettings.config` and I exclude the file in my `.gitignore`-file. How do I get multiple passwords, that are server-specific, to the AppHarbor-solution?

Can I check in a `AppSettings.config` just in **AppHarbor**'s Git-store and not get it overwritten on the next push to **GitHub**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add appsettings that are pumped into your application after it's been pushed to appharbor. These can be used for just about anything.

When looking at your Application on Appharbor.com, there will be a "Configuration Variables" on the left hand side. In that area you can add whatever AppSettings you need, and they will be injected when you do a build.

Once you add a setting (name of "NewAppSetting", value is "We Rule!") you can access them like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NewAppSetting"];//Has a string value of "We Rule!"
```

Comment: I was afraid this might be the final answer, since I've got a lot of configurations that needs to go into my application.

Comment: On the bright side, only the ones that need to be secure need to be done this way. You can have 1 setting that picks out the batch of other settings that while needed on appharbor, are not needed to be secret.

Comment: Maybe you could encrypt those sections of your config file, then you only need to have one Configuration Variable - the password to decrypt.